# RouteValueDictionary initialization and MapRoute issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

Are these two pieces of codes the same?

```
RouteValueDictionary dic=new RouteValueDictionary();
dic.Add("controller", "Home");
dic.Add("action", "Index");
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("Test", "Test/Something", dic);
```

and

```
 RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("Test", "Test/Something", new{controller="Home", action="Index"});
```

I am not getting the same route in the route table. When I use the first option, the keys "controller" and "action" arent in `RouteTable.Routes[0].Defaults.Keys` but are added on the `RouteTable.Routes[0].Defaults.Values`

Do you know what I am doing wrong in the first option?

Comment: third argument of MapRoute is object not a RouteValueDictionary .

Comment: Do you know what kind of expression could i use, as third argument distinct as an anonymous type (i have an instance with all the info (controller, action, params, etc...)

Comment: you can use any type of object with desired properties including anonymous one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can pass object of any type for third parameter but the passed object must have included keys defined in you'r url pattern as it's properties.for example

```
 public class test
    {
        public string controller { get; set; }
        public string action { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    } 

     routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
             new test { action = "Index", controller = "Home", id = "" } 
        );
```

in this case you'r object must include `controller`,`action`,`id` properties.

Comment: Any way if instead a class like "test", i have a dictionary<string,object> with keys and values.

Comment: no.because Dictionary<T1,T2> hase not property called `controller` or `action`.